# Link to add external PWA to homepage

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We want to make our own app store as a website where all the "apps" are PWAs. Since people aren't yet used to the "Add to home screen" feature of PWAs, we want to make all the apps in our app store instantly launch the "Add to home screen" feature of the PWA.

For example, https://pwa.rocks/ is a nice "app store." But to add it to the home screen, users have to first navigate to the page, and then they are prompted to add it to the home screen. We want to skip step one entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case seems prone to abuse and has the potential to do serious damage both to your brand as well as the general perception of PWA's by your customers.

However, to answer your question, you could try using **frames** or **iframes** to achieve this.  Here are the criteria to get the Add to Homescreen banner to show up:

- The web app must not already be installed
- Must meet a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)
- Must have a web app manifest that includes:

  - short_name or name
  - icons must include a 192px and a 512px sized icons
  - start_url
  - display must be one of: fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui
- Must be served over HTTPS (required for service workers)
- Must have registered a service worker with a fetch event handler

When these criteria are met, Chrome will fire a beforeinstallprompt event that you can use to prompt the user to install your Progressive Web App.

Other browsers have different criteria for installation, or to trigger the beforeinstallprompt event.

Source:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Comment: Thanks. This does seem pretty abusive and weird since the user has to have stayed on the page for 30 seconds.